# Simple Server for Hosting XML in Java

Tags: xml, jax-ws, java

I've got some simple dynamic XML that I want to vend out over http at an endpoint using Java (for instance:  `http://localhost:8888/getUpdatedInfo`).

I'd really like to avoid using a framework or third party libraries.  I know for WSDL endpoints it is really simple to host a server using the normal JDK (Using endpoint.publish() in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html)

Is there anything similar for arbitrary HTML/XML?

Comment: Why even use Java for something like that. Seems a bit overkill. A simple Apache server could do the trick and avoid all the dependencies of making your IT department fight to the death with the JVM :)  Don't get me wrong, Java's great, but you don't need a sledgehammer to tack in a few nails. :)

Comment: well you could use restful web services for java, but yeah apache would be simpler.

Comment: A guy I know long ago put together a tiny HTTP server that turned out to be great and lightweight for serving up static content:  http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in the [documentation for com.sun.net.httpserver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html):

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class SimpleHttpServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8888), 0);
        server.createContext("/foo", new HttpHandler() {
            public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
                t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                OutputStream out = t.getResponseBody();
                out.write("hello world".getBytes());
                out.close();
            }
        });
        server.start();
    }
}
```